# Return 'something' instead of null

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this code:

```
select f.name
from Firms F
where
f.id = @{_firmID}
```

Code select name of firm by inserted ID. But if I insert bad ID (nonexisting ID), table return null. I need to rewrite this code to return 'wrong ID' if id not exist for example.
How can I achieve this? Thanks for all reply

Comment: The query itself doesn't return null, it simply doesn't return any rows. That you get null depends on how you process the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested syntax, but you get the idea, I hope:

```
select f.name
from Firms F
where
f.id = @{_firmID}
union
select 'wrong ID' as name
from firms 
where @{_firmID}
not in (select id from firms)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with SQL rather than in application side, then using selectable stored procedure is perhaps easiest way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFirmName(aID INTEGER)
RETURNS(Name VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
  Name = NULL;
  SELECT Name FROM Firms WHERE id = :aID INTO :Name;
  IF(Name IS NULL)THEN Name = 'wrong ID';
END
```

and then

```
SELECT Name FROM GetFirmName(42);
```

Comment: I cant do it in application side. I have acces only to SQL. 
I have this problem only in one case, so stored procedure is not necessary, but thanks.